# $\sum_j e^{i\phi_j}$ vs $\sum_j e^{ip\phi_j}$

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

Let $\phi_j$ be a collection of angles. If $p$ is a positive integer, how is the sum $\sum_je^{i\phi_j}$ related to $\sum_je^{ip\phi_j}$?

Comment: I don't think there is any useful relation. This is a particular case of $\sum_jz_j$ being unrelated to $\sum_jz_j^p$.

Comment: Could you state this general case more rigorously and give a proof?

Comment: A very similar equation appears in quantum mechanics, where your $p$ is the angular momentum quantum number. You are making something like a transformation from the angular to the angular momentum representation. The connection is, that different integer values of $p$ correspond to different orthogonal states. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Just compare $s_1=a+b$ and $s_2=a^2+b^2$. We have $s_2=s_1^2+2a(s_1-a)$ where $a$ is an independent variable. For a given value of $s_1$, $s_2$ is free to take any value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us introduce $x_j=e^{i\phi_j}$, then the sums
$$S_p=\sum_{j=1}^n x_j^p$$
generate the ring of symmetric polynomials in $n$ variables $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. These generators are called [power sum symmetric polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_sum_symmetric_polynomial). They are algebraically independent, i.e. do not satisfy any relation (for $p=1,\ldots,n$). However, $S_{p>n}$ can be written in terms of $S_1,\ldots,S_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Take the case of two angles.

$s_1=e^{i\phi_0}+e^{i\phi_1}$ and $s_2=e^{i2\phi_0}+e^{i2\phi_1}$ are such that
$$s_2-s_1^2=2e^{i(\phi_0+\phi_1)}.$$
As the RHS represents a complex number of modulus $2$ and arbitrary phase, we can conclude 
$$|s_2-s_1^2|=2.$$
In the case of three angles,
$$s_2-s_1^2=2e^{i(\phi_0+\phi_1)}+2e^{i(\phi_1+\phi_2)}+2e^{i(\phi_2+\phi_0)}.$$
The RHS can be any complex number with modulus $\le6$, and
$$|s_2-s_1^2|\le6.$$
Indeed, taking $\phi_0=\frac\phi2, \phi_1=\frac\phi2-\theta, \phi_2=\frac\phi2+\theta$, any point on a circle of radius $r=2(1+2\cos\theta)$ and angle $\phi$ can be reached.

More generally,
$$|s_2-s_1^2|\le n(n-1).$$

Comment: Cases with $p>2$ will lead to more complicated boundaries.